# Creating an inline image based on class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently creating a userscript/extension for Hitbox.tv; the basic idea of the mod is to replace certain words with images like on Twitch.tv, this I have already accomplished. Now what I need help with is finding the easiest way of creating a badge symbol based on certain peoples messages or names. For example, if say, a user with the name of "GamingTom" sends a message, a little symbol will be displayed to the left of their name.

I've had a look through some ways of doing it, but couldn't get anything to work. Two options I believe may work would be using either:

```
<li ng-repeat="message in messages" class="from_GamingTom user buffer_" compile="message.html" ng-class="{isOwner:message.isOwner, isMod:message.isMod}">
```

with `document.getElementsByClassName`

or:

```
<span class="name" ng-click="userTooltip(message.name)" style="color:#FA58AC;border-color:#FA58AC">GamingTom</span>
```

I'm fairly new to javascript so any help will be greatly appreciated. If none of this makes any sense, just say and I'll try to make myself more clear. Many thanks!

EDIT:

Just to let you know, I cannot edit the HTML in anyway. I do not have access to the source files so the only way I could do this is with some sort of javascript in an extension, if that makes sense. Also, the image displayed next to the user will only be for certain users, lets say donators, and will only be a set image; not their avatars or anything. The code I provided came straight from the site after inspecting the html, I picked those two sets of codes because either they both had the users username in it, so I tohught they would be the easiest to use for this purpose. I hope this edit helps a little more!

Comment: It looks like you are using angular and not using jquery.

Comment: I decided to try vanilla javascript because from what I can tell, it is a little difficult to use jquery with Greasemonkey userscripts.

Comment: ng-click,ng-class and ng-repeat are all angular defined attributes. Although I'm not familiar with vanilla js. But assuming you are trying to use ng-class and ng-click you might want to look into an angular solution for accomplishing this.

Comment: It's not clear how either of the options you presented would display an inline image. Can you provide a more complete example of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't provide much code to work with, Ill try expanding off of your first line of code. It looks like you are trying to use Angular to accomplish this. So to do something like that you could just add an `img` tag to your `li` For instance

```
<li ng-repeat="message in messages" class="from_GamingTom user buffer_" compile="message.html" ng-class="{isOwner:message.isOwner, isMod:message.isMod}">
<img ng-src="{message.pic}"/>
</li>
```

Then just style the `img` and `li` with css to get the look you want.

Answer (score 0):

This would be most easily done if each item in the `messages` array had the info about who sent the message.

You would also need to set up a function to get the image associated with a particular user. (I'm assuming it's the user's avatar). For now lets assume you have a function that takes a particular user name, and returns a URL to the image for that user. Let's call it `getImageForUser()`.

Then you would do something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <img ng-src="{{ getImageForUser(message.user) }}" />
    <span>{{ message.text }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

--EDIT--

If you set up the `getImageForUser` function in your controller like this:

```
$scope.getImageForUser = function(username) {
  // query your database or some other way of getting avatar
  return avatar_url;
}
```

then you would need to use the parent scope within your `ng-repeat` like so:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
    <img ng-src="{{ $parent.getImageForUser(message.user) }}" />
    <span>{{ message.text }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```